# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 999

Tags: java

I am trying to make an array to store prime number only 
. My code looks like this:

```
int primenumbers[] =  new int [999];
int num = 6, a = 3, solution = 1;
primenumbers[0] = 2;
primenumbers[1] = 3;
primenumbers[2] = 5;
boolean flag  =  false;
for(num = 6; num <  = 143;num++){  // WORKS UNTIL NUM <  = 142 

    for(int i = 2;i < num/2;i++){
        if (num%i  =  =  0){
            flag  =  true;
            break;
        }
        if(!flag) {
            primenumbers[a]  =  num; // THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
            a++;
        }

        else flag = false;
    }

}
```

as written in the comments when num<= 142 the whole code works fine. when num<=143 i get 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 999

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Once `num == 143`, `a` has an value of 999 which causes the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your incremet of the **a** variable is inside the inner loop. So it increases very fast. Put it outside:

```
int primenumbers[]= new int [999];
int num=6, a=3, solution=1;
primenumbers[0]=2;
primenumbers[1]=3;
primenumbers[2]=5;
boolean flag = false;
for(num=6; num<=143;num++){  // WORKS UNTIL NUM<=142

    for(int i=2;i<num/2;i++){
        if (num%i == 0){
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        if(!flag) {
            System.out.println(a);
            primenumbers[a] = num; // THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE

        }

        else flag=false;
    }
    a++;  //<------- increment it outside the inner loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sz = 0 , primenumbers[] = new int [999];

for(int i = 2 ; i < 143 ; ++i ){
    boolean flag = true;
    for(int j = 2 ; j*j <= i ; ++j){
        if(j % i == 0){
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag){
        primenumbers[sz++] = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `arr.length` to get actual array size, and do not forget, that array's items are counting from `0` to `arr.length - 1`:

```
public static int[] getPrimes(int total) {
    int[] primes = new int[total];

    for (int i = 0, val = 0; i < primes.length; val++)
        if (isPrime(val))
            primes[i++] = val;

    return primes;
}

private static boolean isPrime(int val) {
    if (val < 2)
        return false;

    for (int i = 2, sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(val); i <= sqrt; i++)
        if (val % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay i found the anwser myself i ended the second for loop in a wrong place the working code looks like this

```
int primenumbers[]= new int [9999];
int num=6, a=3, solution=1;
primenumbers[0]=2;
primenumbers[1]=3;
primenumbers[2]=5;
boolean flag = false;
for(num=6; num<=999;num++){

    for(int i=2;i<num/2;++i){
        if (num%i == 0){
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag) {
        primenumbers[a] = num;
        a++;
    }

    else flag=false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you will print a and num in your code you will find the error in your logic. it prints
like

num: 6
num: 7
num: 8
num: 9
num: 10
num: 11
a3
a4
num: 12
num: 13
a5
a6
a7

note for num 11 it increments the value of a two times.

I have done some code changes to fix this.

```
int primenumbers[]= new int [999];
int num=6, a=3, solution=1;
primenumbers[0]=2;
primenumbers[1]=3;
primenumbers[2]=5;

//--------------loop 1 starts here----------
for(num=6; num<=143;num++){  // WORKS UNTIL NUM<=142 
    //System.out.println("num: "+num);

    boolean flag = false;

    for(int i=2;i<num/2;i++){
        //----------loop 2 starts -----------
        if (num%i == 0){
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //----------loop 2 ends -----------
    if(!flag) {
        primenumbers[a] = num; // THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
        //System.out.println("a"+a);
        a++;
    }


}
//--------------loop 1 ends here --------------------------
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primenumbers));
```